# php ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

A little stuck I have the following

```
echo isset($_GET['start_date']) ? $_GET['start_date'] : date('d/m/o');
```

and my IDE is reporting an error I can't see it but if you can you will have my eternal gratitude.

I know I should not be echoing this straight out but in the short term I want to get this up and running so an echo will suffice for now, eventually to be replaced by a variable.

Comment: Your IDE is reporting an error but you can't see it...?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Your IDE doesn't know what it's talking about.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this line. Maybe a problem *before* this line (missing semicolon, unclosed quote, etc). What is the error?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: It might be parsing `echo` as part of the condition, so add some `( )` around the whole ternary. +1 for which IDE?

Comment: @Emyr: `echo` has lower precedence than a ternary operator, I wouldn't count on it unless it's a horribly-broken PHP build.

Comment: What's the error message? Don't just tell us there is an error. Tell us what it says.

Comment: hi all I'm using Netbeans and when after much scratching of my head and tearing of hair I decided to restart the IDE the error had disappeared, should never have doubted myself thanks so much for your help all.

Comment: `should never have doubted myself` lol what? That's a bit arrogant. Everyone should always put theirself in doubt

Answer (score 1):

Update your IDE.
Or use a better IDE.

Answer (score -2):

Add another () around your isset (basically around your 'if' )

Comment: @yes123 Thanks for the supportive feedback. @ everyone else: Oh okay, I though that might fix it, but I see you're right..

Comment: @Gerben: I think "They aren't necessary" and "Useless" means the same. Why vs me?